# PHP Session - Limit of 1 session per IP

Tags: php, session, session-cookies

I have a mystery problem, many sessions are open for each unique IP putting items in my webshop cart. All was working good before ans suddenly without changind anything the cart does not update the quantity when the value change by the customers, so i think that it is due to the fact that i see in the session folder cache that many ID Session are activate for the same IP (like 15 session in 30 sec). Is there a way to limit in wordpress let say 1 session for a unique IP ? Or if you have an idea what code causing this cloning sessions in my theme.
Thanks,
JF

Comment: It is not a good idea to limit the number of sessions per IP, because there could be multiple customers using the same IP address. It is also difficult to help you because we don't have your system. I guess that you yourself can reproduce this basket problem? That means you can check whether every page load initiates a new session. That's the first thing to verify.

Comment: If this is from one user using one browser, it shouldn't happen unless your session setup is misconfigured. Might happen if you have `session.use_only_cookies = 1` (default) and user has disabled cookies in their browser, which would make sessions non-persistent. I'm very curious though, _how can you link the files in session folder cache with IP addresses_?

Comment: I tested the pages and it is only when the cart is activated that the sessions start to oprate. I installed the plugin Panthon Session on wordpress to be sure it is not server related... same thing the problem is still there, On local host all is working good on my pc (test site)

Comment: Ensure that you are starting sessions correctly and you're not calling `session_destroy` or `session_unset` or `unset($_SESSION)` or whatever. Other than that, need to see some code related to your session handling. I would really just build a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) first and see if the problem persists, to see if it's a server issue, or rooted in your code.

Comment: Another strange thing is when i tried 2-4 time to "play" with the recalculate the quantity option in the cart the site timeout completely, i f i want to get back to it online from my ip i have to diconnect and reconnect my router to a new ip...

Comment: ...I checked if i had "session_unset' and i discover 2 lines on two files , i removed it and nothing changed.

Comment: So since it works great on wamp64 (localhost) and not online (like i said i routed the sessions cache to inside wordpress with the plugin Pantheon PHP so with this i am "sure" that the server does not hadle the cache. but there is something wrong somewhere that doesn like the cart code online... Other thing i tried to restore an old database and old files from 1 month ago when all worked perfectly and the problem was there too...

Comment: Ok i found out that multiples IP's sessions was generates by BOTS  often malicious bots if i'n refering to who is IPDB, any way to stop this ?